# Delete local TFS solution and start fresh?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, tfs, version-control

I have downloaded a solution from my TFS server. I was trying a few things out locally and really messed up the whole solution. I want to start with the latest fresh copy from TFS and even move my local project folder. Do I just completely delete my local copy and start again? What happens to everything I checked out for testing. I want to start fresh without effecting the latest server copy at all. Thanks for any help or advise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could undo all pending changes that you might have made by right clicking on the Project name in the Team Explorer and selecting Undo Pending Changes option. Then get latest version of the project from the server.

Comment: the problem with Undo, is that if the changes in the pending changes contains something around 12000 items (merge), the undo takes forever to finish, isn't there a faster way?

Answer (score 0):

It's like Darin says for reverting your local changes, provided you haven't checked anything in.

If you did check in, you can rollback, using the latest TFS [power tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f).

In order to move your local work directory elsewhere, you should unmap the source control folder from your current local target & map it to where you now wish to have it. A thorough description on workspaces/mappings can be found [here](http://www.woodwardweb.com/teamprise/000334.html).